# Библиотека AppCompat - в чём же её преимущества?

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-app-compat-activity

У меня есть компонент `Activity`. Вот исходный код компоновки:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:fontFamily="@font/russo_one"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="TESTAPP"
        android:textSize="48sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Минимальный требуемый уровень API у моего приложения - 16. Для создания Android-приложений я использую среду программирования Android Studio.

В предварительном просмотре компоновка выглядит так:

[image: AVD]

то есть, шрифт Russo One успешно был задан элементу `TextView` (путь к файлу шрифта: `res\fonts\russo_one.ttf`). Но на реальном телефоне всё выглядит иначе:

[image: REAL DEVICE]

Проблема в том, что шрифт не задаётся элементу `TextView`. Я решил данную проблему при помощи использования библиотеки AppCompat (`com.android.support`), а конкретно - при помощи замены компонента `Activity` на `AppCompatActivity`, и тогда шрифт был успешно задан элементу `TextView`.

Но теперь проблема заключается в другом. До использования библиотеки AppCompat моё приложение весило ≈345 Кб. После того, как я добавил эту библиотеку в мой проект, приложение стало весить 2,6 Мб **— это почти в 8 раз больше.** Подскажите, используют ли эту библиотеку современные профессиональные программисты в своих Android-приложениях. В чём же заключается суть использования этой библиотеки? В интернете нашёл не много информации о ней, многие лишь утверждали, что она помогает сохранять красивый одинаковый стиль приложений на более ранних версиях Android... У моего приложения я хочу задать минимальный требуемый уровень API 15. Стоит ли **мне в данном случае** пользоваться этой библиотекой и если стоит, то какими её преимуществами руководствоваться? Очень мало русскоязычных справочников, документаций, форумов на эту тему в интернете я сумел найти.

Может быть, лучше скопировать только определённые нужные мне классы из библиотеки AppCompat и вставить их в моё приложение? Ну, допустим, мне нужен только класс `AppCompatActivity` в данном случае, его я и скопирую в моё приложение в отдельный пакет. Я не пользуюсь классом, к примеру, `FloatingActionButton`, вот и не копировать его в моё приложение вовсе. Не плохо ли поступить именно так со всеми классами этой библиотеки?

Comment: если вам нужен material design для API меньше 21, то вам необходимо использовать библиотеку AppCompat. Взять отдельные классы из нее и расчитывать, что это будет работать не стоит, но можете попробовать (ничего не получится). com.android.support - набор библиотек поддержки гугл, в котором их больше 20 штук. AppCompat только одна из них и "отвечает" за стиль Material на устройствах с API ниже 21. У каждой библиотеки есть вполне определенное название, которое известно всем, не надо придумывать им какие то свои, если хотите, чтобы вас понимали

Comment: @pavloff, просто длинное название пакета. ОК, сейчас уберу свои названия.

Comment: AppCompat вполне достаточно, все знают названия библиотек поддержки. в библиотеке основной объем - ресурсы (собственно стиль Material), а не классы, так что их "выкидывание" в любом случае несущественно сократит объем

Comment: @pavlofff, ясно. Но почему проблема такая со шрифтом? Он не задаётся элементам через XML без библиотеки AppCompat. Можете что-то подсказать по этому поводу? Тут ещё дело в том, что у меня многовато различных элементов, которым я хочу шрифты *различные* задавать, делать это через Java-код - *самоубийство.*

Comment: атрибут `android:fontFamily` включен в API Android [только с API 26](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml). Так же он включен в библиотеку поддержки AppCompat с ревизии 26. У вас мин апи 15 и данный атрибут не инфлейтится (просто пропускается, так как мин апи ниже поддерживаемого атрибутом, а это апи 26). с таким мин апи использовать данный атрибут вы можете только через библиотеку AppCompat или использовать сторонние библиотеки, которые, возможно меньшего объема

Comment: @pavloff, значит получается, что если я подключу к своему проекту библиотеку AppCompat ревизии 26, то шрифты будут успешно задаваться даже в API 15?

Comment: да, ревизии 26 и выше. использовать имеет смысл последнюю релизную версию библиотек поддержки (сейчас ревизия 27)

Comment: @pavlofff использоваться эти шрифты будут с 26 api. На остальных девайсах это будет обычный стандартный шрифт. Верно?

Comment: @TimurMukhortov нет, при использовании библиотеки поддержки AppCompat и AppCompatActivity на всех API будет одинаковый вид

Comment: @pavlofff хммм, а почему тогда Lint в случаях, когда используешь атрибуты вашего минимального начинает подсвечивать и писать "можешь заигнорить атрибут, он не сработает на всех версиях" (примерно так). Он все равно будет работать, даже если скажем атрибут добавили в 21, а ранее его нет? Тип support сделает всю грязную работу?

Comment: @pavlofff, у меня тот же вопрос, что и у @TimurMukhortov. Когда я указываю атрибут `android:fontFamily` у элементов, Android Studio меня *ругает,* хоть и отображается в предварительном просмотре всё корректно.

Comment: @pavlofff, я попробовал добавить строку `xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` в основную компоновку и задать шрифт элементам следующим образом: `custom:fontFamily="@font/russo_one"`. На реальном телефоне всё отлично, а в предварительном просмотре шрифты не задаются элементам...

Comment: В основную компановку всмл без AppCompat?

Comment: @TimurMukhortov, я заменил основной компонент `Activity` на `AppCompatActivity` и задал основную тему приложения `Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light`. Не совсем понял Ваш вопрос.

Comment: предварительный просмотр - штука не надёжная и опираться на то, что она показывает не стоит никогда. Смотреть надо всегда на реальном устройстве или эмуляторе - именно так и будет на самом деле.  Темы нужно использовать полные, а не базовые, то есть - Theme.AppCompat.Light. базовая - каркас для нескольких тем и некоторых стилей не имеет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Класс `Activity` находится в стандартной библиотеке андроида на каждом девайсе. Засим не нужно подклчать к-л библиотеки для использования этого класса. Но в этом кроется главная проблема - эта библиотека обновляется только с обновлением ОС девайса, что происходит или редко или никогда. Таким образом использование `Activity` приведёт к тому, что на разных девайсах с разными версиями ОС (в т.ч. минорными) у вас будет разное поведение в разных местах, разные баги и большие проблемы с их воспроизведением и фиксом. И это не говоря о разном отображении одних и тех же элементов интерфейса.

Засим следует всегда использовать библиотеку поддержки и класс `AppCompatActivity` - так у вас на всех девайсах всех возможных версий будет одна и та же версия классов и бороться вам надо будет в случае чего не со всем зоопарком версий, а только с одной. Ну и интерфейс будет везде одинаково выглядеть.

Вот эта же инфа в [документации](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up) (относительно использования `Toolbar`, но это относится и ко многим другим вещам, в частности к `TextView`, которое автоматически заменится на `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView`, в котором много улучшений и исправлений. В т.ч. со шрифтами):

> Beginning with Android 3.0 (API level 11), all activities that use the
>   default theme have an ActionBar as an app bar. However, app bar
>   features have gradually been added to the native ActionBar over
>   various Android releases. As a result, the native ActionBar behaves
>   differently depending on what version of the Android system a device
>   may be using. By contrast, the most recent features are added to the
>   support library's version of Toolbar, and they are available on any
>   device that can use the support library.
>
> For this reason, you should use the support library's Toolbar class to
>   implement your activities' app bars. Using the support library's
>   toolbar helps ensure that your app will have consistent behavior
>   across the widest range of devices. For example, the Toolbar widget
>   provides a material design experience on devices running Android 2.1
>   (API level 7) or later, but the native action bar doesn't support
>   material design unless the device is running Android 5.0 (API level
>   21) or later.

Comment: Аа, вот почему у меня проблема с заданием шрифтов была. То есть, в `AppCompatActivity` все такие элементы, как, например, `TextView`, `Button` автоматически будут заменены на `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView` и `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton` соответственно? Может тогда стоит сразу именно их в компоновке использовать, а не `android.widget.TextView` и `android.widget.Button`?

Comment: @nick, да, документация утверждает, что всё автоматом заменяется. Но лично я видел проблему со шрифтами в случае, если использовать `android.widget.TextView` вместо `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView`. Засим можно и так и так, а если что-то не работает - заменять на `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView`

Comment: А какое пространство имён использовать в случае `AppCompatTextView`? Я имею ввиду каким образом задавать шрифт: `android:fontFamily="@font/russo_one"`, или `app:fontFamily="@font/russo_one"`, или `custom:fontFamily="@font/russo_one"`, или просто `fontFamily="@font/russo_one"`? или как-то иначе

Comment: @nick, насколько помню надо `app:fontFamily="@font/russo_one"`

Comment: пространство имен библиотеки поддержки не имеет какого то определенного названия. как вы укажите в заголовке разметки название схемы, так оно и будет называться. то есть может быть и app и custom ( [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/867088/%d0%91%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%b0-appcompat-%d0%b2-%d1%87%d1%91%d0%bc-%d0%b6%d0%b5-%d0%b5%d1%91-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b8%d0%bc%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0?noredirect=1#comment1403039_867088) вы указали custom, соответственно обращаться нужно будет к атрибутам так custom:fontFamily="..."

Answer (score 4):

Основная идея `AppCompat` в том, чтобы на старых устройствах поддерживать фичи введенные в более свежих API

Ну за это приходится чем-то платить, понятно чем: тем что в состав приложения включаются либы, которые в более свежей версии находятся уже в составе ОСи

В вашем случае это вылилось в лишние 2 мегабайта. Вы уж решите для себя или вам нужен красивый шрифт стоимостью 2 лишних мегабайта или остаетесь на 345 кб - решать вам.

**P.S.** По мне 2 мб - это ни о чем, на дворе 21-й век и крохобориться из-за пары мегабайт как-то неприлично.